# Help with installing boot grub in Windows 10

Tags: grub2, windows, bootloader

I'm having a hard time trying to install  on my Windows 10 the Grub bootloader. I downloaded the Ubuntu 18.04.4-desktop-amd64 ISO then  ran the Ubuntu live session, then I ran this command `sudo fdisk -l`

SSD:

[image: Image of my SSD]

According to some internet articles I need to shrink my current SSD at least by 400 MB in order to format a boot partition as EFI FAT32 with a proper flag, and with that I will be able to install GRUB there. I have never used a Linux distro before.

Would someone here give me guidance me with proper commands in order to shrink my current drive which has 223 size, but only has a free space of 33 GIB? I only need a 400 MB boot partition.

Once I have installed Grub, finally I would be able to ran the grub configuration to finally fix the HPET of my motherboard firmware among other things.

With GRUB booting Windows, I can access to the configuration of the motherboard firmware allowed in Asrock, and with that force High Event Precision Timing to Disable Cause in a regular way my motherboard firmware is causing issues with HPET forced enable even if I disabled it, so with the GRUB there is a configuration to force HPET to disable, and force the Windows timer to 3.580 MHz.

Comment: Since you do not wish to use Ubuntu, this is a Windows-only question; therefore, this belongs in https://Superuser.com our Q&A site for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

[GRUB](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/) is automatically installed by the Linux installer, [Ubiquity](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Ubiquity), when you install Ubuntu. However, you can use GRUB for Windows only, according to https://www.aioboot.com/en/install-grub2-from-windows/ which provides detailed instructions.

=

For the rest of us, here's the sequence to use for installing GRUB by Ubiquity for a dual boot of Windows and Ubuntu:

Download Ubuntu's ISO file at https://ubuntu.com/download

or for a supported 'flavour' with a different Desktop Environment, download from https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours .

Next, check for download errors by https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0

Make a LiveUSB following these instructions on another Linux PC https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#0

or on a Windows PC https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0

Once you make a LiveUSB, install it following these steps https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#0

and when you get to step 6, [Allocate Drive Space](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#6-allocate-drive-space)
You can choose **Something Else** to resize the Windows NTFS partition and make room for Linux.

Looking at the picture you provided, there's an EFI partition there already; that's what Windows 10 does by default. Only if your PC had Windows 7 or earlier installed first, would it be partitioned with the Legacy MBR Partition table, which would not have an EFI partition.

Comment: But I just wanted to use my current Ubuntu ISO which is the  18.04.4 LTS and with the LIVE-USB via Terminal, be able to shrink my current Windows partition and allow 400 MB to be partitioned as EFI or something to install the grub there? how can i do that?

I don't want to reinstall my Windows 10, also I dont want to Install ubuntu OS,  I just need the Grub boot loader. :(

Comment: Actually I never had a windows 7 installed before, this is a ryzen 5 1600 Asrock b350 fatality k4 gaming motherboard.

So do you think I can use that EFI partition of 100 MB as the new boot partition for the GRUB? sorry my ignorance, and sorry for my English, you are very kind.

Comment: I'm guessing that as that Efi partition says (100 M) stands for 100 Megabytes and has not data at all, so do you think I can try this command in order to install the grub?

Example:
sudo grub-install --recheck --no-floppy --root-directory=/ /dev/sda2  ?

Cause today i tried that but not on sda2<-- and i had an error like:
Installing for i386 pc platform grub install error failed to get canonical path of 'cow'/

Comment: Looking at the picture you provided, there's an EFI partition there already; that's what Windows 10 does by default. Making a new EFI partition would break Windows. The existing EFI partition can be started by Ubuntu and Windows 10. But, the only point of installing GRUB is if you are installing Ubuntu. Are you doing a new install of Ubuntu? If so, you follow the instructions from Ubuntu which I linked above.

Comment: Uhmm, so theres is not way that i can create a boot partition for Grub? 
using the method (Try ubuntu) via terminal? 

I just wanted to find a way to create a partition only for Grub, without modifying my data in my Windows SSD. 
afffff :/

Comment: Cause with the Grub boot, I can access to the configuration of the motherboard firmware allowed in Asrock, and with that force High Event Precision Timming to Disable

Cause in a regular way my motherboard firmware is causing issues with hpet forced enable even if I disabled it, so with the Grub there is a configuration to force hpet to disable, and force the Windows timer to 3.580 MHz timer acpi_pm if using useplatformclock

Is the only Way here in Venezuela I cannot do a RMA of my motherboard, situation is is difficult :(

Comment: To shrink a Windows partition should use windows disk management or a windows partition manager program.

Comment: Hello Crip659 i did via Windows diskmanagement shrink or allocated 400 MB partitionate as fat32 , but the thing is to run the Trial Ubuntu, and if not EFI? make fat32 GPT? and find a way to install grub in that one, I will try and report.

Comment: Nevermind is to complicated, I was hoping to find a guy here that was able to explain  me how to either  mount that EFI windows 10 partition and modify with the Grub boot, and with this be able to bypass my motherboard firmware and make things better.

:'( thanks everyone.